# The module browserhistory doesn't seem to work and raises KeyError

Tags: python

Running the example [from pip](https://pypi.org/project/browserhistory/) modified to choose the `'chrome'` browser, I get a `KeyError`

script:

```py
import browserhistory as bh

dict_obj = bh.get_browserhistory()
data = dict_obj.keys()
print(data)
data = dict_obj['chrome'][0]
print(data)
```

output:

```py
dict_keys([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/raj/Desktop/anilyzer/myproject/main.py", line 6, in
data = dict_obj['chrome'][0]
KeyError: 'chrome'
```

What is happening?

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? Do you not understand what a KeyError is? Why did you expect that the key "chrome" exists?

Comment: You dict is empty (by the first `print`), so obviously you will get a `KeyError`... What is your question?

Comment: @techtalk Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've modified your Question to ask something! Articulating a good question and having a minimal example (which you actually do!) is key to getting good answer on SO. You can edit your Question further with the [edit] button below it if you'd like to improve my changes to make your question even clearer. Your question can then be nominated (may happen automatically) to be re-opened and go into another review queue.

Comment: this module is not maintained but i have done some changes in that module and now it is working atleast in liniux you can use that

https://github.com/rajgupta81/browserhistory

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the module is maintained and cannot detect your browser(s)
https://github.com/kcp18/browserhistory

The function `bh.get_browserhistory()` should return a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) where the type of browser is the lookup key. Displaying this as you do shows that the dictionary is empty.

```py
>>> data = dict_obj.keys()
>>> print(data)
dict_keys([])
```

This is why you get a `KeyError` when attempting to read a specific key from the `dict`

```py
>>> d = {}
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>> d["something"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'something'
```

However, there appears to be a different project which may do what you want https://github.com/pesos/browser-history

This is from reading the GitHub Issues: https://github.com/kcp18/browserhistory/issues and I cannot comment on its quality or safety!

Comment: The same is my problem